# How can I show C++ code documentation in Xcode 9.3?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, xcode9, code-documentation

I´m developing software based on C++ in Xcode and want to have (at least) the same convenience for code documentation as if I was developing for Swift or objc.

Example:

```
std::string myString("hello");
if (myString.empty()) {
    // do something
}
```

If I want to know exactly what `.empty()` does, I would like to Option-Click on the function and get the documentation overlay with information from e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty, exactly as it does for objc and Swift.

How is this possible?

Current output just looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot. According to [Apple's Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051), as of Xcode 8.3

> 3rd party docset support is now deprecated and will no longer be
>   supported in a future release of Xcode. (30584489)

There are alternate doc browsers, like [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) which allow you to install your own documentation. But this does not give you what you're hoping for.

I have verified that adding a C++.docset into `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation` does not work. (likely a directory left over from an earlier Xcode) In fact, removing this directory entirely does not affect Xcode 9.x from correctly displaying the default documentation.

Comment: This is likely the answer the O.P. is looking for -- Apple really only supports documentation for the languages it "owns" (Objective-C & Swift) and a feature request for other language documentation support should be sent in for Xcode via http://bugreporter.apple.com

Answer (score 5):

This is for your custom class. You can add your comment like this - in the header I do this

```
 /**
     * Method name: name
     * Description: returns name
     * Parameters: none
     */
```

here is a sample I did -

```
#ifndef test_hpp
#define test_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class myclass{
private:
    std::string name_;

public:

    myclass(std::string);
    /**
     * Method name: name
     * Description: returns name
     * Parameters: none
     */
    std::string name();
};

#endif /* test_hpp */
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe it could be misunderstood, but I was searching for the code documentation of the C++ code itself, not for custom classes etc. So when I´m clicking on std::string.empty(), it should display the content from e.g. here: en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty

Answer (score 4):

I'll upvote Deb's answer but I was also looking at this for a little while.

[Markdown in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html) is somewhat brittle in Xcode 9.

It works for function declarations:
[image: Multiline comment]

[image: Singleline comment]

And also for callouts:
[image: Callouts]

Documentation comments seems to work well for function declarations, but doesn't work at all for lines of code *within* the functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe it could be misunderstood, but I was searching for the code documentation of the C++ code itself, not for custom classes etc. So when I´m clicking on `std::string.empty()`, it should display the content from e.g. here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty